# Use of $nin on embedded document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a schema like this in MongoDB:

```
var Customers = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, trim: true, index: true, default: null, sparse: true },
    facebookId: { type: String, default: null, trim: true, index: true },
    friends: [friends]
});

var friends = new Schema({
    customer: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Customers', required: true },
    lastGame: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'games', required: true, default: null },
    lastGameTime: { type: Date, default: null }
});
```

Now in **friends** array I have reference of all the customer who are Facebook friend of the particular customer.

Now what I want to do is I have a screen where I want to show all the customers but there I don't want to those customers who are already my Facebook friends i.e for an example lets suppose I have **10 customer in total from 1 to 10**, I am **customer no** **4** who have **customer 1,3,5,6 in friends array** so my result on the screen should be of **user 2,7,8,9,10**

I will really be thankful if someone can tell me the way to this stuff by using Query of MongoDb. I have searched and found **`$nin`** usage but that works in simple array. I don't get how I can implement this query on an embedded document as in the case of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using **$nin** with a simple approach first of all I select all the friends of a particular customer in an array then by using **$nin** I filtered all the friends from the query and got my result.

Answer (score 0):

Look into $elemMatch. This will allow you to identify a specific document in an embedded document array

[ElemMatch MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/)

You can also use $elemMatch in combination with $nin